# drupal 7 anonymous user sessions not storing

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm currently building a website using Drupal and I use an external php script to do the login. When the login is successful, the session variables are supposed to be updated with the user data.
While I was developing that script, I kept it only visible to administrator users, but now that I have it available to everyone, as an anonymous user, the session variables are updated on the php script, but the pages in drupal can't read them. But the problem only happens as an anonymous user. As an administrator the script works great

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
When you know that the user is logged with your php script, log him with drupal. It's kind of synchronization.
For that, you can use: [user_external_login_register](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7)